# Работа с gprof2dot в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Пишу в командной строке

```
gprof2dot -f pstats profile_results.prof | dot -Tpng -o profile_results.png
```

Выдает ошибку:"dot" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Что делать?
Graphviz установлен. Windows 10

Comment: `apt install graphviz` Ну или не `apt`, а ваш пакетный менеджер.

Comment: @mkkik устанавливал через .msi, но dot не находит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прописать в системной переменной Path путь к dot.exe, например C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\  если не меняли путь при установке Graphviz.

Answer (score 0):

Запуск построителя графа

gprof2dot -f pstats start_ppi.prof | dot -Tpng -o start_ppi.png

не работает, как я понял, по причине кодировки консоли cp1251

Я сделал иначе gprof2dot -o s.res -f pstats start_ppi.prof выгрузил в файл s.res

А затем

dot -Tpng -Tps s.res -o start_ppi.png и получил картинку вызовов